# main method not being called in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

So i have this code which solves the quadratic equation in java (android development) and it isnt doing anything!!!! The button when i press it does not give the answer at all... i cant even check if it is doing it correctly.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class QuadraticEquationSolver extends Activity {
public void main(String[] args){

    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText X2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.X2);
            EditText X = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.X);
            EditText Num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num);
            TextView ans= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalans);
            double x2 = Integer.parseInt(X2.getText().toString());
            double x = Integer.parseInt(X.getText().toString());
            double num = Integer.parseInt(Num.getText().toString());
            double finalNum = ((x*-1) + (Math.sqrt((x*x)-(4*x*num))))/(2*x2);
            ans.setText("answer: " + finalNum);

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quadratic_equation_solver);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quadratic_equation_solver, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: just wondering how are you testing this? Generally you should be creating buttons and setting the listener in the onCreate()

Answer (score 6):

First of all, welcome to Android development.  I would highly recommend as a starting point you read the [App Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) and related guides on the SDK documentation site, as they will help you greatly in your new endeavour.

Android does not use a single entry point (i.e. main method) so your code will not be called.  You will want to move all that code into `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quadratic_equation_solver);

    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText X2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.X2);
            EditText X = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.X);
            EditText Num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num);
            TextView ans= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalans);
            double x2 = Integer.parseInt(X2.getText().toString());
            double x = Integer.parseInt(X.getText().toString());
            double num = Integer.parseInt(Num.getText().toString());
            double finalNum = ((x*-1) + (Math.sqrt((x*x)-(4*x*num))))/(2*x2);
            ans.setText("answer: " + finalNum);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't do any android programming, but I doubt Android will ever call your main method. The content of this main method must probably be in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 4):

`onCreate()` is your `main()` equivalent in Android. Your `main()` function will never be called. The contents of `main()` should go in `onCreate()`.